# JavaScript function does not work. Help a newbie :\

Tags: javascript, function

I'm working on a linear gradient generator.
I wanted to add a random gradient function, so it picks the background style and sets a gradient with two random colors. Everything worked until i added this random function. It looks like this:

```
function getRandomInRange(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function setRandomGradient() {
    body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, rgb("
    + (getRandomInRange(1, 255)
    + " ,"
    + (getRandomInRange(1, 255)
    + " ,"
    + (getRandomInRange(1, 255)
    + "), rgb("
    + (getRandomInRange(1, 255)
    + " ,"
    + (getRandomInRange(1, 255)
    + " ,"
    + (getRandomInRange(1, 255)
    + "))";
}
```

getRandomInRange works well, but setRandomGradient isn't working and console shows me an error like:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'

Poitning to the last semicolon before a function brakets close. But if i remove the semicolon, the error is starting to point to something else, like closing brakets or something else

Comment: You've opened a lot of parentheses that don't get closed...

Comment: To be a bit more specific: `(getRandomInRange(1, 255)` has two opening parenthesis and only one closing.

Comment: @ivar 
Wow, thanks. It worked. I don't know how i didn't noticed that!

Comment: @bashka You're welcome. One other note: The goal of Stack Overflow is to be a useful resource for _future_ visitors having the same problem. A title like the one you put on this question doesn't help anyone identifying if it is about the same issue. I recommend reading through [ask] before you ask another question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use a [JavaScript IDE](https://jaxenter.com/top-5-javascript-ide-146609.html) like [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) to help you with syntax errors

Try this:

```
function getRandomInRange(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function setRandomGradient() {
    body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, rgb("
        + (getRandomInRange(1, 255))
        + " ,"
        + (getRandomInRange(1, 255))
        + " ,"
        + (getRandomInRange(1, 255))
        + "), rgb("
        + (getRandomInRange(1, 255))
        + " ,"
        + (getRandomInRange(1, 255))
        + " ,"
        + (getRandomInRange(1, 255))
        + "))";
}
```